# Error coming while building c code in full system mode of gem5

Tags: cpu-architecture, gem5

i am using gem5 simulator in full system mode and getting error as Aborted(core dumped).
i am using command as : " build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/coep/full_system_images/disks/arm-ubuntu-natty-headless.img  --kernel=/home/coep/gem5/full_systems_images/binaries"

Comment: This is not the build command, that is the run command. You need to give fuller error logs, exact gem5 version, where images came from.